# How to use combobox with if statement on Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qtserialport

So i am using the combobox on QT, in the combobox i added two devices names and i wanted to change the name in combobox to send data via radiobox to my port i tried the if statment but it doesn't work.

```
 #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <QMessageBox>

QSerialPort serial;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    serial.setPortName("COM3");
    serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud19200);
    serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);                         
    serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    ui->comboBox->addItem("SP157B");
    ui->comboBox->addItem("JSP");
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    if(ui->comboBox->currentText())
    {
        if(ui->radioButton->isChecked())
        {
            QByteArray Rouge("\x15\x7B\x1A\xAA");       
            serial.write(Rouge);
            QString t = ui->label->text();
            ui->label->setText(t+"\n15 7B 1A AA");
        }
        if(ui->radioButton_2->isChecked())
        {
            QByteArray Vert("\x15\x7B\x19\xA9");    //allume en vert
            serial.write(Vert);
        }
        if(ui->radioButton_3->isChecked())
        {
            QByteArray Orange("\x15\x7B\x1B\xAB"); 
            serial.write(Orange);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ui->comboBox->currentText()` is a `QString`.  Do you want to check if the `QString` is not empty?

Comment: I want use if(ui->radioButton->isChecked()) when th combox is "SP157B" but i can't use the if statement, i want to Know is there a another way ? Also thanks

Comment: You likely want to compare a `QString` to a string literal and not worry that the `QString` came from a combobox.

Comment: I didn't get that can you give me an example please?

Comment: `QString text =ui->comboBox->currentText();` then  `if (text.compare("SP157B") == 0) { // the text is matched}`

Comment: You could also use the value of `ui->comboBox->currentIndex()` if the order of the items in the combo box is fixed like your example. 0 is the first item added to the combo box.

Comment: Thanks I tried your method, it complied but since it's a school project i need equipments to test it. Thanks anyway you been a huge help